why it differs when i put two parts of the function in to different file?
I am a beginner in C language, currently learning about file classification management, and I have encountered some issues. Why does the output differ when I place the helper functions in a separate source file compared to when they are together with the main function? The compiler I am using is VS2022.Here is my code:
#include "0.h"

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    printf("Please enter the number n: ");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum += signs(i) / factorial(i);
    }

    printf("%e", sum);

    return 0;
}

#include "0.h"

double factorial(int num);
int signs(int loc);

int signs(int loc)
{
    int sign = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= loc; i++)
    {
        sign *= -1;
    }

    return sign;
}

double factorial(int num)
{
    int den = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        den *= i;
    }
    return den;
}

the head file:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

I just want to learn the reason
add:when they are together,it comes out the right answer;when it is seperated,it turns out to be a false.

Try putting the declarations in the header.

Aside: int den = 1; should be double den = 1;

Use the same file structure as in the linked duplicate. Function definitions + header guards in the .h file.

thanks ,it has been solved by putting declarations in the header,but i still want to know why it's different

Each .c file is compiled independently, in light of all the header files it #includes, directly or indirectly.  Thus, when prototypes for signs() and factorials() are only in the same .c file with the function implementations, no other .c file sees them.  In particular, there are no prototypes visible at the point where your main() calls these functions. Your compiler should be emitting warnings about that, and you should be paying attention to them.  For historical reasons, your compiler tries to guess what the correct function signatures are, but it gets that wrong.
